# Wordpress - Getting the queried type (Category, archive, author etc)

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

E.g
1. When someone clicks "curators" category, it will bring them to curators category page and display posts of "curators" category with its own featured image.
or
2. When someone clicks author "john", it will bring them to john page with all his posts and display "john" featured image.

Question is how can I retrieve this "curators" or "john" as I want to display a featured image to different pages. Say extract "john" go to the folder find john.jpg and display his archived page with his header image. Or go to "explorers" category page and display the category page with explorer featured image.

I got this but it's only for category:

```
<? $cat = get_query_var('cat');
$yourcat = get_category ($cat);
?>
#headerimg {
background-image: url(<?php echo       ithaka_directory_uri() .'/images/'. $yourcat-    >slug .'.jpg'?>);
}
```

Did what pgk told me to: get_queried_object(); but not working.

```
<?php $term = $wp_query->get_queried_object(); ?>

#headerimg {
background-image: url(<?php echo ithaka_directory_uri() .'/images/'. $term .'.jpg'?>);
}
```

It return me with "**Fatal error**:  Call to a member function get_queried_object() on a non-object in **/home/departur/public_html/wp-content/themes/ithaka/inc/custom-header.php** on line **97**
"

Comment: Not `$wp_query->get_queried_object()`, only `get_queried_object()`, because you don't have a instance of `$wp_query`. You must do `global $wp_query` if you want to use it like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I managed to fix it from this site: 
http://stanhub.com/display-wordpress-taxonomy-term-name-in-taxonomy-page/

```
<?php if (is_archive()) { 
$taxonomy = get_queried_object();
?>

#headerimg {
background-image: url(<?php echo ithaka_directory_uri() .'/images/'. $taxonomy->slug .'.jpg'?>);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_queried_object()` function [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object):

From Codex

> Retrieve the currently-queried object. For example:
>
> if you're on a single post, it will return the post object
>
> if you're on a page, it will return the page object
>
> if you're on an archive page, it will return the post type object
>
> if you're on a category archive, it will return the category object
>
> if you're on an author archive, it will return the author object

etc.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't seem to be working. Had an error with the page.

Answer (score 0):

My friend help me fixed these. Its checking as well if there's file exists. If it doesn't, it will output a default image.

```
<?php
    if (is_archive()) { 
        $taxonomy = get_queried_object();
        if (is_a($taxonomy, 'WP_User'))
            $dataused = $taxonomy->user_nicename;
        elseif (is_a($taxonomy, 'WP_Term'))
            $dataused = $taxonomy->category_nicename;

        if (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/wp-content/themes/ithaka/images/'. $dataused .'.jpg'))
            $dataused = ithaka_directory_uri() .'/images/'. $dataused .'.jpg';
        else
            $dataused = $header_image;
    } else
        $dataused = $header_image;
    ?>
        #headerimg {
        background-image: url(<?php echo $dataused; ?>);
    }
```